# NSManagedObject relationship NSSet iteration

Tags: cocoa, nsset

I have a subclassed `NSManagedObject` (ObjectA) which has a relationship one-to-may to another subclassed `NSManagedObject` (ObjectB). I get the ObjectB `NSSet` from ObjectA's generated method.

I want to determine if an ObjectB with a given 'name' exists in the returned `NSSet` (e.g. `ObjectB.name == "xxx"`).

What is the most efficient way to determine the `NSSet` contains the object instead of iterating/comparing my way through the whole `NSSet`?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To get a set with all objects matching the condition:

[aSet filteredSetUsingPredicate [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like %@", aString]]

A simple count would be enough to create an expression useable in a condition.

[[aSet filteredSetUsingPredicate [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like %@", aString]] count]